# Returning to main view from UIWeb view after HTTP call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, http, soundcloud

I'm using the [SoundCloud Cocoa Wrapper API](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/README.md). To connect the users SoundCloud account to their Facebook account I use this:

```
[scAPI performMethod:@"POST"
        onResource:@"connections"
    withParameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"facebook_profile", @"service",
                    @"http://imc", @"redirect_uri",
                    @"touch", @"display", //optional, forces services to use the mobile auth page if available
                    nil]
           context:@"newConnection"
          userInfo:nil];
```

which works perfectly fine: I can see that the connection is made on my SoundCloud connections settings page. The thing is once the Facebook UIWebView page does it's job the screen goes white and it doesn't return to the view of my application. In other words the UIWebView doesn't get the message to 'go away'. How do I send it this message?

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

Some other info that might help:

```
#define kCallbackURL              @"imc://oauth"      //remember that the 
myapp protocol also is set in the info.plist 
PLIST URL identifier                    com.imc 
PLIST URL Scheme Item 0          imc
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Twitter OAuth it is done in the following way. After user presses authorize button on UIWevView, the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated is called to close that view:

```
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(OAuthTwitterController:authenticatedWithUsername:)]) [_delegate OAuthTwitterController: self authenticatedWithUsername: _engine.username];
[self performSelector: @selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) withObject: (id) kCFBooleanTrue afterDelay: 1.0];
```

So I guess you should write something like this:

```
[self performSelector: @selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) withObject: (id) kCFBooleanTrue afterDelay: 1.0];
```

to be called after your job is done with web view